# Can I share the review of my Phd thesis with my external reviewers?

Tags: thesis, thesis-committee

I have submitted my Ph.D thesis for review. My main supervisor already finished her task and sent me back the review with the grade. The three external reviewers just got their copy from the faculty committee office to review it.

The external reviewers are asking me about the instructions and the review format that my university want. Am I allowed to share my main supervisor review with them (without showing the final grade maybe?)?

Comment: You should forward that request to your advisor. I assume that there are regulations and guidelines that would answer their question.

Comment: @Roland Yes I understand. But can I share the review also with them?

Comment: Ask your advisor. (At my Alma Mater *you*  would not be allowed to have the official review from your advisor.)

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of having several reviewers is that each reviewer is asked to provide their *independent* opinion. To allow some reviewers to see the opinion of another reviewer before they‘ve submitted their own independent opinions would risk prejudicing them, and would undermine the review process. Such practices are a recipe for groupthink and [poor decision making](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink#Case_studies).

I don’t know if your university would frown on this practice. But from an ethics perspective, it’s pretty obvious you should not do this.